# How to pad extra rows so that each case will have 15 records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, padding

I have the following stored procedure:

```
select rcl.ReportRunCaseId AS CaseId,
ROW_NUMBER() over(
  PARTITION BY rcl.reportruncaseId 
  ORDER BY rcl.reportruncaseid) as Row, 
YEAR(rce.EcoDate) AS EcoYear,
SUM(rce.NetInv) AS NetInv, 
SUM(rce.NDCash) AS NDCash, 
SUM(rce.DCash) AS DiscCash, 
SUM(rce.GrossGas) AS GrossGas, 
SUM(rce.GrossOil) AS GrossOil, 
SUM(rce.NetProdTax) AS NetProdTax, 
SUM(rce.NetOpCost) AS NetOpCost, 
SUM(rce.NetFixedCost) AS FixedCost, 
SUM(rce.NetTransCost) AS NetTransCost, 
SUM(rce.NetOtherCost) AS NetOtherCost 

From PhdRpt.RptCaseEco_6 rce
INNER JOIN PhdRpt.ReportCaseList_6 rcl 
ON rce.ReportRunCaseId = rcl.ReportRunCaseId 
AND rce.ReportId = 6
inner join PhdRpt.EcoIndicators_6 ei 
ON ei.ReportRunCaseId = rcl.ReportRunCaseId 
where rce.ReportId = 6
group by rcl.ReportRunCaseId, year(rce.EcoDate)
```

This gives an output of:

```
CaseId    Row     EcoYear ....
   1       1        2005
   1       2        2006
   1       3        2007
   1       4        2008
   1       5        2009
   1       6        2010
   2       1        2005
   3       1        2005
   3       2        2006
   3       3        2007
   4       1        2005
   4       2        2006
   .
   .
   .
   .
```

What I need to have is 15 rows for each CaseId. The missing data in the remaining columns should be null.

My first thought was to create a temp table with Row numbers 1-15 and then join the tables together but it gave me too many records.

```
  IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
      Rows CHAR(2)

)

Insert INTO #temp (Rows)
Values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5), 
       (6),(7),(8),(9), (10),
       (11),(12),(13),(14), (15)
```

How should I approach this? Union?

Comment: What should happen if there are more than 15 entries for a caseId?

Comment: Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird I hadn't thought about having more than 15 entries. Usually there are only 15 at the most. In the case that there are more than 15, I would still use the window function to count the rows and just pad the cases that have less than 15 up to 15.

Comment: So, you're okay with not showing 16 and up?  In that case, Jon's answer is great.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  I'd recommend creating a `Numbers` table for this, and future purposes, but it's not material.  Get a list of numbers from 1 to 15, then `LEFT JOIN` this against your existing logic.  Return a record for each number, with values from your reporting tables where present.

Comment: I am getting extra records because the left join is creating 15 instances for every record. For example, CaseId 1 has 6 records so the join is causing there to be 90 records in the output.

Comment: Indeed, you'll need to join the two using the value in `Number` (or wherever you get your list of numbers) to the row number in your existing query.  Note that you can use a `FULL OUTER` join if you decide you want to show more than 15 rows where they are present in your right-hand logic.